# Problem: dropna() method is returning NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

Having problems with the .dropna() method. I have created a new variable `energy_c` which is a copy of `energy` but with `mont` being more or equal to `0.1`.

I then took out the columns with nothing in after printing them and then am trying to drop all rows that have `NaN` values in the remaining columns. However my output is returning `NaN` values even after using `.dropna()`.

```
energy_c = energy.loc[energy.loc[:, 'mont'] >= 0.1].copy()
energy_c.columns[energy.isna().all()].tolist()
drop_cols = energy_c.loc[:,['EndDate', 'Ref', 'dis']]
energy_c.drop(drop_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
energy_c.dropna()
print(energy_c)
```

Could someone advise as to what I have done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropna` is not an inplace method, try `energy_c = energy_c.dropna()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
energy_c.dropna(inplace = True)
```

This does the operation inplace and returns None, according to the documentation.