# Dataframe column float with missing values to proper date format, e.g. 201912 to DEC-2019

Tags: python, dataframe, date-format

I want to create a new column in dataframe by converting the `'YYYYMM'` column to the proper date format.

```
YYYYMM   want the following format 
201910   OCT-2019
nan
201911   NOV-2019
201903   MAR-2019
nan
```

I tried following codes:

```
if df['YYYYMM'].notnull:
    df['YYYYMM1']=[pd.to_datetime(df['YYYYMM'], format= '%Y%M') for x in str(df['YYYYMM'])]
```

Result:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is unsliceable
```

```
if df['YYYYMM'].notnull:
    df['YYYYMM1']=[datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m').strftime('%b%y') for x in str(df['YYYYMM'])]
```

Result:

```
ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%Y%m'
```

Comment: ***`ValueError: time data '0'`***: Are you sure the column `'YYYYMM'` is of typ `str` and there are no value with `0`?

Comment: yes, there is no value 0. type of column 'YYYYMM' is float

Comment: [Edit] your question and show the output of `print(df.dtypes)`. Relevant [problem-dropna-method-is-returning-nan-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322643)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  You need to convert the float to a string and get rid of the decimal.  Also %M is minutes.  You need to convert to %m for month.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([201910,201911,201903,np.nan,np.nan],columns = ['YYYYMM'])

df['CONVERTED_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0]),format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%b-%y')

print(df['CONVERTED_DATE'])

0    Oct-19
1    Nov-19
2    Mar-19
3       NaT
4       NaT
```